# ¿Cómo ejecutar JQuery en el navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para poder ejecutar un script de Javascript en la barra de búsqueda del navegador, por ejemplo, habría que escribir `javascript:alert('hola')` y aparecería un pop-up. ¿Se puede ejecutar JQuery en el navegador (en la barra de busqueda) de alguna manera, como `jquery: aquí código`?

Comment: Podrias poner el jQuery dentro de una funcion js y haría exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Para poder ejecutar código escrito en JQuery necesitas antes invocar a dicha biblioteca, de otra forma solo obtendrás error de sintaxis con el símbo que usa query que es `$`

Comment: Pues no, JQuery es una librería escrita sobre Javascript. Javascript es un lenguaje de script, son cosas muy diferentes.

Comment: Puedes ejecutar jQuery en la consola del navegador si presionas F12.

Comment: @derloopkat siempre que tenga dicha biblioteca disponible en su proyecto no?

Comment: @BetaM si abre cualquier página que use jQuery, la librería ya cargada allá.

Comment: Pero no busca cualquier página que tenga jQuery y de ser el caso deberías aclararlo por qué debería inspeccionar una a una hasta que la encuentre

Comment: No puedes ejecutar javascript en la barra de dirección (o búsqueda) del navegador y, realmente no tiene sentido, es decir, si tu intención es realizar pruebas, hay herramientas como el fragmento de código (codesnippet) aquí mismo, o sitios como [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [CodePen](https://codepen.io/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Poder puedes, a condición de que jQuery esté disponible en la página actual.

Otra cosa es que debas.

No sé en otros navegadores, pero en Safari necesitas activar una opción que viene desactivada por defecto y supongo que es motivos de seguridad.

Puedes intentar este código:

```
javascript:alert($(".post-text").children().first().text())
```

Como se puede ver, se usa código jQuery, (prefijo `$` y selectores al estilo jQuery. Este código debería mostrar un `alert` con el título de tu pregunta.

En mi Safari normal me da primero esta advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo activo en el menú desarrollador sólo para demostrar que funciona y, no me gusta nada esta advertencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de eso, me pide la constraseña de administrador y todo para habilitar esa opción. No hay duda, la seguridad puede estar en peligro si dejas activada esa opción. Vigilamos que no hay hackers en la costa y desactivamos para pequeña prueba...

Ejecutamos rápidamente de nuevo:

```
javascript:alert($(".post-text").children().first().text())
```

Et voilà, funciona!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no es recomendable, por motivos de seguridad.